# Error when I am using boost library

Tags: c++, boost

Im trying to use the library Boost but I can't compile any code .

I install boost with follow commands in Linux mint

```
$ sudo ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
$ sudo ./b2 install
```

This is my program, I copy and paste from this site https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Libraries/Boost

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void hello_world() 
{
  cout << "Hello world, I'm a thread!" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
  // start two new threads that calls the "hello_world" function
  boost::thread my_thread1(&hello_world);
  boost::thread my_thread2(&hello_world);

  // wait for both threads to finish
  my_thread1.join();
  my_thread2.join();

  return 0;
}
```

When you tried to compile it, this error occurs

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -g cppc.cpp -o test
cppc.cpp:32:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc , char * argv[]){
              ^
cppc.cpp:32:33: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc , char * argv[]){
                                 ^
/tmp/ccOvZcci.o: En la función `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:206: referencia a `boost::system::generic_category()' sin definir
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:208: referencia a `boost::system::generic_category()' sin definir
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:210: referencia a `boost::system::system_category()' sin definir
/tmp/ccOvZcci.o: En la función `boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int, char const*)':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/exceptions.hpp:51: referencia a `boost::system::generic_category()' sin definir
/tmp/ccOvZcci.o: En la función `boost::detail::thread_data_base::thread_data_base()':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:152: referencia a `vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base' sin definir
/tmp/ccOvZcci.o: En la función `boost::thread::start_thread()':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:186: referencia a `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()' sin definir
/tmp/ccOvZcci.o: En la función `boost::thread::~thread()':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:261: referencia a `boost::thread::detach()' sin definir
/tmp/ccOvZcci.o: En la función `boost::thread::get_id() const':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:751: referencia a `boost::thread::native_handle()' sin definir
/tmp/ccOvZcci.o: En la función `boost::thread::join()':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:777: referencia a `boost::thread::join_noexcept()' sin definir
/tmp/ccOvZcci.o: En la función `boost::detail::thread_data<void (*)()>::~thread_data()':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:90: referencia a `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()' sin definir
/tmp/ccOvZcci.o:(.rodata._ZTIN5boost6detail11thread_dataIPFvvEEE[_ZTIN5boost6detail11thread_dataIPFvvEEE]+0x10): referencia a `typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit stat
```

What I can do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linker error, not a compiler error.  You have to link with the Boost libraries.

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g cppc.cpp -o test -lboost_thread -lboost_system
```

More about this can be found in “Using and building the library” section of the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/libs/thread/):

> Boost.Thread depends on some non header-only libraries.
>
> - Boost.System: This dependency is mandatory and you will need to link with the library.
> - Boost.Chrono: This dependency is optional (see below how to configure) and you will need to link with the library if you use some of the time related interfaces.
> - Boost.DateTime: This dependency is mandatory, but even if Boost.DateTime is a non header-only library Boost.Thread uses only parts that are header-only, so in principle you should not need to link with the library.

---

Maybe you want to use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) (C++11) which does not require linking 3rd-party libraries?

Comment: This is a more well researched answer than mine. Good job, Henri.

Comment: This works but when I try to execute the binary file this happen s.

./test: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.65.1:         cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @MarcoLeslie I don't know where `b2` installed your libraries.  You could try with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./test`

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell your compiler that your code wants to use parts of boost. Add the flags `-lboost_thread -pthread`.

I recommend reading about what libraries are and how to link them into your program.